# Detect delete key in ACCESS Combo Box

Tags: vba, ms-access

Need to detect the delete key being pressed when cursor in Combo Box.  Looked at examples on the web and here. Just the delete key.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use the KeyPress event it returns the ascii code of the key pressed.  You can do what you need with that info from there.

```
Private Sub yourcontrol_KeyPress(KeyAscii as integer)  
if keyascii= 127 then
'do some stuff  
end if  
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I stumbled upon it myself and the only other answer is not correct in this case...

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.navigationcontrol.keypress) says:

> The Backspace key is part of the ANSI character set, but the Delete
> key isn't. If you delete a character in a control by using the
> Backspace key, you cause a KeyPress event; if you use the Delete key,
> you don't.

In other words: `KeyPress` event **does not capture** `Del` key.

As an alternative, use `KeyDown`:

```vb
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyDelete: cmdLoadDelete_Click
    End Select
End Sub
```